# Image not showing in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, cross-browser, height

I have an image I use as a ruler between content. It's a simple 1px x 1px image that I stretch out depending on the size I need.

If I stretch it to, say, 250px wide and leave it at 1px in height, it will not show up in IE (I'm currently on 10, but it doesn't show on the earlier versions either). It does, however, show in Firefox and Chrome. If I raise the height to 2px, it will show in IE, but it is too thick in the other browsers that could view it at 1 px in height.

example:

```
<img src="images/blackline.jpg" style="margin-top:35px; margin-bottom:20px;" height="1" width="275"><br>

NEW TEXT ITEM HERE<br>

<img src="images/blackline.jpg" style="margin-top:35px; margin-top:20px;" height="1" width="275">
```

Anyone know a way to get this to work properly?

Comment: Need to see some code..

Comment: Yeah, if you're `floating` or `absolutely positioning` or setting a `display:none` on this `img` we can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: I haven't done any of those things, just added simple images. No idea why it wouldn't work.

Comment: if it's just a simple solid black line, do you really need an image for that? why don't you use a `<hr>` tag and/or a CSS border to do it?

Comment: CSS border wouldn't work because the content is within a different size to that of the line. The <hr> tag's attributes no longer work with HTML5, and is a rather ancient method these days anyway.